# If error then skip to next step to script Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

One of the steps of the script is to get information about the current weather of a city. But sometimes the city name is not found in the API database if I am looking for, causing an error that completely pauses the rest of the script. I would like to know what I can adjust so that if there is an error searching the city, it will skip to the next step of the script.

```
function TudoCompleto() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

//Clima
  spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTXML(\'Clima\'!F20,"//*[@id=\'page_team_1_block_venue_info_3\']/div/div[1]/dl/dt")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('Clima!F21:F45').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1:A25').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

//Clima 2
  spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTXML(\'Clima\'!F20,"//*[@id=\'page_team_1_block_venue_info_3\']/div/div[1]/dl/dd")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('Clima!G21:G44').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1:A24').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

//CLIMA  
  spreadsheet.getRange('Clima!A3:B8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clima");
  var apiKey = "MY API KEY"; // Or you can try my key

  var cityName = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  // Go to https://openweathermap.org, register and get a free API key
  var apiCall = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityName +"&appid=" + apiKey;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiCall);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  var weather = data["weather"][0]; //It's an array
  var sys = data["sys"];
  var main = data["main"]
  var location = data["name"];
  var country = sys["country"];
  var weatherDesc = weather["main"];
  var temp = main["temp"];
  var minTemp = main["temp_min"];
  var maxTemp = main["temp_max"];

  var weatherData = [
    ["Location:", location],
    ["Country:", country],
    ["Weather:", weatherDesc],
    ["Teaperture:", temp],
    ["Min Temp:", minTemp],
    ["Max Temp:", maxTemp]
  ];

  sheet.getRange(3, 1, weatherData.length, weatherData[0].length).setValues(weatherData);



//The API Call works
// The Data will be retrieved like below JSON file.
//{"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},
//"sys":{"country":"JP","sunrise":1369769524,"sunset":1369821049},
//"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],
//"main":{"temp":289.5,"humidity":89,"pressure":1013,"temp_min":287.04,"temp_max":292.04},
//"wind":{"speed":7.31,"deg":187.002},
//"rain":{"3h":0},
//"clouds":{"all":92},
//"dt":1369824698,
//"id":1851632,
//"name":"Shuzenji",
//"cod":200}


  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // planilha ativa
     var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Clima"); 

  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

    var cel = "H"+ i //

      if (sheet.getRange(cel).getValue() != "")  {   

         for (var u = 1; i < 1000; u++) {
            var cel2 = "M"+ u //

             if (sheet.getRange(cel2).getValue() == "")  { 

                 sheet.getRange("M"+u).setValue(sheet.getRange(cel).getValue());
                 break;
             };
      }
   }
};
  spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('Clima!F16').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
}
```

When the API does not find the city I am looking for, the error happens on line 41 (var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch (apiCall);)

If this error happened, I would like instead of pausing the script, it would continue from line 83 (var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet (); // planilha ativa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UrlFetchApp parameters to check if valid response comes back:

> muteHttpExceptions :  Boolean : If true the fetch doesn't throw an exception if the
>   response code indicates failure, and instead returns the HTTPResponse.
>   The default is false.muteHttpExceptions

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app][1]

```
options = { 'muteHttpExceptions' : true}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiCall, options)
if (reponse != 404){ code block to do if good response till line 83}
line 83
```

Check what you get as a bad reponse object. But bad response should be 404.

Comment: Could you give me an example in practice? I'm sorry but I have a big problem with English, it would help me a lot if you could give me an example of how I could use it, it would help me a lot to understand how I would add it to my script. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ```
options = { 'muteHttpExceptions' : true}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiCall, options)
if reponse != 404 { code block to do if good response till line 83}
line 83
```

Comment: var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiCall,{muteHttpExceptions:true});

Comment: That way I put it, it seems, worked perfectly ... Am I correct? If so, thank you very much, if possible, answer the question without comment, so that I can vote as resolved through your answer.